# Count the amount of times a word is repeated in a field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I would like to count the amount of times a word is repeated in a field in a text from my form in MS Access - something like Excel's `=COUNTIF(K2:K100,"*tm-9*")`.

I have come across `=Sum(IIf ..` but I need to know how many times it is shown including repeats as in the example below.

[image]

Comment: What is an example of a word you want to find, and an entry that contains the word?

Comment: Please replace you link to example string

Answer (score 2):

You can find the count with only one line of code:

```
p = "Some string with one tm-9 or more tm-9s"
s = "tm-9"
WordCount = (Len(p) - Len(Replace(p, s, ""))) / Len(s)

WordCount -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in function which will do count.
Try creating your own function. This one will work, only assign your own field and criteria values, and the variable - Res will return the number you want.

```
Dim Field as String
Dim CriteriaText as String
Dim FieldLength as Integer
Dim CriteriaLength as Integer
Dim Res as Integer
dim j as Integer

Res = 0

Field = 'assign the field value here 
CriteriaText = 'assign the criteria her
FieldLength = LEN(Field)
CriteriaLength = LEN(CriteriaText)

WHILE FieldLength >= CriteriaLength 
  j = InStr(Field , CriteriaText)
  IF j > 0 THEN
    Res = Res + 1
    Field = REPLACE(Field, CriteriaText, "", 1, 1)
    FieldLength = LEN(Field)
  ELSE
    CriteriaLength = FieldLength  + 1
  END IF
Loop

MsgBox Res
```